# definition of a $\kappa$-small simplicial set

Tags: category-theory, cardinals, simplicial-stuff

Let $\kappa$ be a [regular cardinal](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+cardinal). A set $X$ is $\kappa$-small, if $|X|<\kappa$.

> What does it mean for a simplicial set $X\colon \Delta^{op}\to Sets$ to be $\kappa$-small.

I can imagine at least two possible definitions:

1. $\forall n\geq 0:X_n$ is a $\kappa$-small set,
2. The set $\bigsqcup_{n\geq 0} X_n$ is a small set

These are different for the regular cardinal $|\mathbb{N}|$.

Lurie mentions $\kappa$-small simplicial sets in HTT but I can't find a definition there.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: In the case of $|\mathbb{N}|$, the assertion is about finite sets.

Comment: Okay, you might be right. I think Lurie means a simplicial set $X$ such that each $X_n$ is $\kappa$-small as a set, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think the second interpretation is reasonable for $\kappa = \aleph_0$. In fact, it is only satisfied for the empty simplicial set.

Comment: @ZhenLin, do you also think that Lurie means (1) when he speaks about $\kappa$-small simplicial sets? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of reasonable definitions which only differ for $\kappa = \aleph_0$. However, I think what Lurie means is this:

> A **$\kappa$-small simplicial set** is a simplicial set with $< \kappa$ non-degenerate simplices.

This is *not* equivalent to either of your definitions. For instance, if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category freely generated by an idempotent endomorphism, then $N (\mathcal{C})$ is degreewise $\aleph_0$-small but not $\aleph_0$-small. Indeed, one can infer that Lurie means for "$\aleph_0$-small simplicial set" to be a synonym of "finite simplicial set" from the proof of (Corollary 4.4.2.4 and) Proposition 4.4.2.6 in [*Higher topos theory*].

Incidentally, a simplicial set is $\kappa$-small if and only if it is $\kappa$-compact.

Comment: Thank you Zhen Lin. Do I understand you correctly: If $\kappa > |\mathbb{N}|$, I can take (1) as the definition of a $\kappa$-small simplicial set?

Comment: Yes. Or, for that matter, (2).